# jQuery override an on() event with another on() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 files, file 1 (`head.tpl`) contains this default function operation

```
$(document).on("click", "#blackout", function(){
    closeSkyBox();
});
```

That is the default operation I want to run, and it works.

On my second page, I would like to override the operation that is in `head.tpl` with this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#blackout", function(){
    closeSkyBox(function(){
        pev_for_country = '';
    });
});
```

So, now when I test the code, each one runs, so If I were to place an alert (for testing reasons) I get two alert boxes. How can I make it so only the one in the second page runs, and the one in `head.tpl` is disabled. Then when I don't override it say on a third page, the one in `head.tpl` runs?

Comment: First of all for your information on is not an event it is a binding function for events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [*jQuery's* `.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(document)
    .off('click', '#blackout')
    .on('click', '#blackout', function () {
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: So, it would look like this: `$(document).off("click", "#blackout").on("click", "#blackout", function(){`?

Comment: Yep, something like that.

Comment: If this is the correct answer for you, please accept it for other people who read this in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove all event handlers, but you should be cautious: what if other libraries add event handlers that you don't want to remove subscribe to this event?  Also, if you add an additional event handler at a later date, this would obliterate it.

A better approach, I think, is to create a function that you can override:

```
function blackoutClick() {
    closeSkyBox();
}
```

And set up your click handler:

```
$(document).on("click", "#blackout", function(){
    blackoutClick();
});
```

Or, as Paul pointed out in the comments below, you don't even need to wrap that handler in an anonymous function, you can just use the cleaner:

```
$(document).on("click", "#blackout", blackoutClick );
```

Then, in your second page, you can just modify that function:

```
function blackoutClick() {
    closeSkyBox(function(){
    pev_for_country = '';
});
```

Comment: You could always pass the _listener_ into `off` too, if you want to be specific about it. I'm used to always doing that because I usually write vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

I believe another way to do it is also to set the event to null...

```
$(document).on('click', '#blackout', null);
```

before you re-set it on your second page.